# Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 admin menus unclickable

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 recently on my vps and after logging into admin panel I found out the menu bar links are unclickable and submit buttons such as in index management also not working.I reset the file permisions to 700 for directories & 600 for files but still the problem persists.Please help.

Comment: The files/folder permissions as per Magento recommendation should be 644/755. Please change it to 644/755 and try it out..

Comment: are there any errors in the console? Is the `var` and `media` writeable (775)?

Comment: Actually the file permissions were 644/755 when I installed and when I found out about this problem I changed the file permissions to 600/700 as listed in magento docs.

Answer (score 0):

Please unmerge the javascript if its merge.

In phpmyadmin select core_config_data table and search dev/js/merge_files as path and make their value as 0.

Comment: sorry I couldn't find this path, search result also displayed empty.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v91ZG.png see the given screen shot. Go phpmyadmin and select your database-> core_config_data -> select search and select path operator as like %...% give js as value and then select go. Then change the value for dev/js/merge_files as 0.